# Get next enumeration value in C?

Tags: c, dynamic, enumeration, expansion

For class I need to make a dynamically expanding hash table that expands when the number of bindings reaches certain values - 509,1021, 2039, 4093, etc. I understand just about everything else but I'm not sure how to check which value the table should expand to next.

I think that we're supposed to use enumerations, but I don't understand how to get the "next" enumeration value. I.e., if my hash table currently has 1022 bindings I should expand the underlying array to size 2039, but how do I know how to do that? Or am I approaching this the wrong way?

Sorry in advance if this is a stupid question, but it's not addressed in my book and I'm still very new when it comes to C.

Comment: I don't think enumerations are the way to go here; you cannot iterate over enumerations, nor index into them.

Comment: OK, thanks. I was hoping there /was/ a way to do that...is there anything more elegant than an array of possible sizes, then? I guess I'll go with that.

Comment: 509, 1021, 4093 are all just 3 less than powers of 2. (Are you sure 2039 isn't supposed to be 2045?) You could just compute those.

Comment: No, one of the professors here (Sedgewick) has done research into "optimal" points at which to resize, and we have to use those. At least, that's the reason if I remember from my Algorithms course last year. The full list: 509, 1021, 2039, 4093, 8191, 16381, 32749, and 65521.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use enumerations for this purpose in C.

You probably want to put the thresholds in a constant array, and maintain an index to point at the current threshold:

```
const int thresholds[] = { 509, 1021, 2039, 4093 };

int i_thresh = 0;

...

if (num_elements > thresholds[i_thresh])
{
    i_thresh++;
}
```

Comment: I guess I'll go with that then. Thanks for your help!